# Is there any way to limit the choices displaying in autocomplete fields in Django admin based on the foreign key just selected in another field?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, autocomplete-fields

I encounter a problem when using the autocomplete fields in Django admin.

```
#model.py
class Party(models.Model):
    pass

class Address(models.Model):
    party = models.ManyToManyField(Party,through='MailAddress')

class MailAddress(models.Model):
    party = models.ForeignKey(Party,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Mail(models.Model):
    party = models.ForeignKey(Party,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mail_list = models.ForeignKey(MailAddress,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    

#admin.py
class AddressInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Address.party.through

class PartyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AddressInline]

class MailAddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['address']

class MailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['mail_list']
```

My question is whether I can make the autocomplete field display MailAddress field for the selected Party only?  Thanks.